# How can I change the color of the android progressbar(horizontal) to different sections?

Tags: java, android

How can I change the color of the android progressbar(horizontal) to different sections?
I want to set the color of the bar to different sections.
For example, 0 to 10 is blue, 10 to 50 is red, and 50 to 100 is yellow.
please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0WXI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get percent using `progressbar.getProgress()` method.

and change color using `getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter`

```
progressbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

p.s] 코드나 이미지를 같이 올리셔야 답변 확룰이 올라갑니다.
(You have to upload the code or image together to increase the confirmation of the answer.)